# How do I create a subtitle in HTML5? I need to know for a school project

Tags: html

I am asked to create a local web page using HTML5 and use a bunch of elements, all which I understand how to do except add a subtitle.

I have no idea what to add to even start.

Comment: Are you sure that you have the terminology correct?  There is no such thing in html5 as a subtitle.  There is a title tag, which is what shows in the browser tab, that is part of the head tag section.  By convention it is best practice to have this match an h1 tag in the body.  Other headings from h2..h6 are part of the html5 standard.  You might try looking at [the list of html5 elements here](https://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-html-markup-20121025/elements.html).    [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element) also provides a helpful page describing the various elements.

Answer (score 0):

When looking at the Section Heading Elements below, I can assume that h1 is the title, and h2 is the subtitle in this case.

```
<h1>Heading level 1</h1>
<h2>Heading level 2</h2>
<h3>Heading level 3</h3>
<h4>Heading level 4</h4>
<h5>Heading level 5</h5>
<h6>Heading level 6</h6>
```

Comment: What if his subtitle is sub to a `<h2>`? And a `<h3>` already exists

Answer (score 0):

To add a subtitle to your HTML5 web page, you can use the `<h2>` tag. This tag is used to define headings in HTML, with `<h1>` being the highest level heading and `<h6>` being the lowest level heading.

Comment: Then use <h4>, if it is already <h4>, then use the lower headings continually